# What should collator do exactly?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, collation

Suppose we have an audio classification task (AudioMNIST).

My pipeline and other pipelines I’ve seen consist of the next steps:

1. Read the dataset (the data samples).
2. Do the base transforms (merge the audio channels, change the bitrate, etc).
3. Split the dataset into the train one, the test one, etc.
4. Do the main transforms (different for the train and the test) such as the augmentation.
5. Batch (along with the sampling).
6. Pad/Truncate the batch samples.
7. Do the forward pass with the batch.
8. <…>

I saw the scheme:

- Dataset or a subclass - pp. 1., 2., 3., 4.
- Collator - p. 6.

Either:

- Dataset or a subclass - p. 1.
- somebody else - pp. 2., 3., 4.
- Collator - p. 6.

Or:

- Dataset or a subclass - p. 1.
- somebody else - p. 3.
- Collator - pp. 2., 4., 6.

What should the collator do and what shouldn’t? (The main question.)
What is the correct scheme?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with pytorch, so I'll give the pytorch answer.

Pytorch data utils has a `Dataset` and a `DataLoader`. tl;dr, the `Dataset` handles loading a single example, while the `DataLoader` handles batching and any bulk processing.

The `Dataset` has two methods, `__len__` for determining the number of items in the dataset and `__getitem__` for loading a single item.

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
```

The `DataLoader` is passed a list of outputs from the `Dataset` (ie `batch_input = [dataset.__getitem__(i) for i in idxs]`). The batch input is sent to the `collate_fn` of the `DataLoader`.

```py
def my_collate_fn(batch):
    ...

dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset, batch_size, collate_fn=my_collate_fn)
```

In terms of thinking about what to do where, the `Dataset` should handle loading single examples. The `Dataset` will be called in parallel, so tasks that are CPU-bound should go in the `Dataset`. Loading from disk (if applicable) is also typically done in the `Dataset`.

The `collate_fn` handles converting a list of outputs from your `Dataset` into whatever format your model wants. Since the `DataLoader` deals with a batch of data, it can be more efficient to apply batch processing steps. Stacking tensors, padding to length, generating masks or other bulk tensor ops work well in the `collate_fn`.

In general, think of the `Dataset` as running multi-process on single examples, while the `DataLoader` running a single-process on a batch of examples.